# Converting char to string in c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, windows-10

I need to convert a char (called reader) to a string. I tried this:

```
                    /*stringstream ss;
                    string convert;
                    ss << reader;
                    ss >> convert;
                    cout << convert;*/
```

And this:

```
string convert (1, reader);
```

Both do not set a value for ss or convert. I can't figure out why.

I have the name of a wavfile in a text document. I want to read from the file and open that wav. However, .get returns a char, and I need a wstring. So I'm trying to convert from char to string, then string to wstring.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
char c = 'a';
std::string h;
std::string str(1, c);
std::cout << str;
std::cin >> h;
return 0;
}
```

Why does the above code work but not the code above it?

Comment: Define "char (reader)".

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik It has been defined. If it wasn't, my code wouldn't compile. That is not the issue

Comment: Let's try this again: explain what "char (reader)" means. These are, obviously two words. The first word is a data type in C and C++. The second word is inside parenthesis, and is a valid word you can find in an English dictionary. But, it's not clear what is the result of putting them together in this manner. You need to explain what you mean by that. I was asking *you* what that meant.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik My apologies; I misunderstood. I mean that there is a variable in my code called reader. When you see "reader" in my example code it is the char I am trying to convert. I did this to avoid being told "You didn't tell us what reader is supposed to be". It is a char defined in my code that I did not provide in the question.

Comment: @majneeds2chill Please see this link:  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: char buf[2]; buf[0]=reader; buf[1]=0; std::string str=buf;

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik Still nothing. I tried your example, it compiled, and still nothing. :-(

Comment: NOTICE: Please refer to new edit

Comment: Works for me without any issues.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik OK. This must mean the error is caused by another problem. Like I said, I am not the only person to ever have this problem. Give me a moment to reorganize. Then I'll get back to you. Then I'll post an edit

Comment: _"A similar question was shut down due to the unlikely hood of helping future visitors. The irony is stunning!"_ What's "ironic" about it and how has it changed with this repost?

Comment: Next time construct your [MCVE] _before_ posting, so as not to waste our valuable time.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit You don't have to answer questions if you don't want to. Anyway, what I meant by ironic was that the question was shut down because it wasn't likely to help future visitors. Obviously, as I am having the same problem, that wasn't true.

Comment: Well I am certainly sorry that we did not spend millions of man-hours constructing this website and community for your own personal benefit.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit I think you took that the wrong way. I don't mean any offense at all. I'm just starting out, and this has been a great tool for me. :-)

Comment: @majneeds2chill : You can use a initialiser list `std::string s = { a_char };`

Comment: NOTICE: Please refer to edit

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit Please don't tell me I offended you. This was not my intent at all. I really do need help and no one seems to want to help!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I realize now I never correctly formatted my reply, and you never saw it. I would appreciate if you read it. Thanks!

Comment: You still need to post a [MCVE].

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No argument there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem description seems quite clear, but under-specified:

> ”  I have the name of a wavfile in a text document. I want to read from the file and open that wav. However, .get returns a char, and I need a wstring.

`.get()` is an ungood choice when you want to read more than one character, as you do.

If the file name is on its own line then you can use `getline` from the `<string>` header to read it, which preserves any spaces in the name. But the C++ standard library i/o does not deal sensibly with encodings, so possibly you'll have to use system specific functionality for the reading. This depends much on your text file.

Using the filename, now in a `string` or `wstring`, to open a file, also runs into encoding issues.

But as long as the filename only contains ASCII characters you can just pass it to an `ifstream` constructor. Visual C++, your compiler, offers an extension that takes `wstring` argument, so that will work. Make sure to specify binary mode for the stream, since a ".wav" file is binary.

Answer (score 1):

Don't read the data as chars, use an `ifstream`.

Here is an example taken from a [cplusplus.com tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/) (scroll down to *Text files*).

```
string line;
  ifstream myfile ("example.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    while ( getline (myfile,line) )
    {
      cout << line << '\n';
    }
    myfile.close();
  }

  else cout << "Unable to open file";
```